# In Xcode 8 private pod core data not generating models for objective-c

Tags: core-data, cocoapods, code-generation, xcode8

I have a private pod that I would like to include a core data object model. In the pod I have:

- Added a core data object model named "Database"
- set Code Generation Language to "Objective C"
- set Codegen to "Class Definition"
- Added a model named "Model"

In the main app I am unable to access import "Database+CoreDataModel.h" or "Model+CoreDataClass.h"

How do I access the model classes from my private pod?

Comment: In your podspec, you added them in the source, right? Once you did a "pod update", on your main app, do you see the files? Did you preserved the paths?

Comment: With xcode 8 the files are supposed to generated in the derived data. The xcdatamodeld is in the pod correctly.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?